# Why is consing in Lisp slow?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I read in the book 'On Lisp' that one should avoid excessive use of `cons` in the body of expanded macros.  Why is `cons` considered to be an inefficient operation?  Does Lisp not do structure sharing with the cons cells?

Comment: Can you give a section reference in the On Lisp book? Perhaps we could help explain what that statement means given its context.

Comment: Section 7.8, Macro Style, pg 101, Graham writes "Macros are often used to implement general-purpose utilities, which are then called everywhere in a program. Something used so often can’t afford to be
inefficient. What looks like a harmless little macro could, after the expansion of all the calls to it, amount to a significant proportion of your program. Such a macro should receive more attention than its length would seem to demand. Avoid consing especially. A utility which conses unnecessarily can ruin the performance of an otherwise efficient program.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to understand the jargon first.

**CONS** is a primitive operation to create a fresh cons cell.

**Consing** means allocation of memory on the heap in general, not only cons cells: Consing of numbers, Consing of arrays, Consing of CLOS objects, ...

The definition from the 'memory management glossary' says:

1. **cons**(1) In Lisp, cons is a primitive operation creating a list element (from English "CONStruct"). By extension, a cons is the element created.
2. **cons**(2) (for full details, see allocate) Allocation is the process
   of assigning resources. When
   requested to by the program, an
   application memory manager or
   allocator allocates a block of
   memory(2) for the program to store
   its data in. Allocation is also
   known as consing, from **cons**(1).

So, Graham uses the second meaning.

If Graham says 'Avoid consing especially. A utility which conses unnecessarily can ruin the performance of an otherwise efficient program.' - that means: avoid unnecessary memory allocation on the heap. But this can be true for any code - macro, function, whatever.

That was particular true when computers had less memory and Garbage Collection was more costly (especially when it needed to scan swapped out memory in virtual memory systems, where the physical memory is smaller than the virtual memory).

Today consing is less an issue, but can still be relevant.

Take for example a the function READ-LINE, it reads a line from a stream and 'conses' a new string. Note that the string is not built out of conses, but it is a vector. We mean here 'allocates a string on the heap'. If you have a large file with lots of lines, it can be faster to have a routine that gets a buffer and which fills the buffer with the line characters (there are vectors in Common Lisp with a fill pointer for this). That way the line buffer is just one object and can potentially be reused for calls to this line reading function.

See this example in the Allegro CL documentation: [Some techniques for reducing consing when processing very large text files](http://www.franz.com/support/tech_corner/cons-tricks-121306.lhtml).

Answer (score 7):

I don't think [cons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) is slow. It doesn't create a new copy of the entire list, it just appends a new element onto the front of a linked list.

If anything is slow, it's that it has to allocate some memory for the new node. If you're creating lots and lots of nodes it might be better to create them all in one go instead of one-by-one.

Comment: and this is what confused me - cons should be a constant time operation.  In this case, I'm a little fuzzy about just why I wouldn't want to cons often in the expanded macro code

Answer (score 6):

Actually consing is quite fast in good implementations, but you *can* gain better performance by avoiding it. You can safely use destructive operations if the things you alter have been freshly created by yourself, as in this example:

```
CL-USER> (defun non-destructive ()
           (progn
             (reverse (loop for x from 1 to 100000 collecting x))
             nil))
NON-DESTRUCTIVE
CL-USER> (defun destructive ()
           (progn
             (nreverse (loop for x from 1 to 100000 collecting x))
             nil))
DESTRUCTIVE
CL-USER> (time (non-destructive))
(NON-DESTRUCTIVE) took 140 milliseconds (0.140 seconds) to run 
                    with 2 available CPU cores.
During that period, 156 milliseconds (0.156 seconds) were spent in user mode
                    0 milliseconds (0.000 seconds) were spent in system mode
94 milliseconds (0.094 seconds) was spent in GC.
 1,600,024 bytes of memory allocated.
NIL
CL-USER> (time (destructive))
(DESTRUCTIVE) took 93 milliseconds (0.093 seconds) to run 
                    with 2 available CPU cores.
During that period, 93 milliseconds (0.093 seconds) were spent in user mode
                    0 milliseconds (0.000 seconds) were spent in system mode
63 milliseconds (0.063 seconds) was spent in GC.
 800,024 bytes of memory allocated.
NIL
```

So: Yes, avoiding consing can improve performance, but you should only use destructive modification if you know what you're doing. I would not say that consing is "slow" per se, but nonetheless avoiding it can be beneficial. If you compare the difference in allocated memory (which takes its time), it should be clear why the second version is faster than the first one.

Comment: I'm still curious to know why this is the case. Does it just come down to memory allocation - as Mark Byers suggested above?

Comment: I am no expert about whats going on under the hood of Lisp implementations, but I'd say: Yes, allocation and GCing is what it boils down to.

Comment: On Lisp was published in 1993. The GCs of today are light years beyond what was in actual implementations back then. consing now is much cheaper than then. (although still not free, as danlei shows)

Answer (score 2):

Consing, which is Lisp jargon for dynamic memory allocation, isn't slow. But it adds overhead to the program. You cannot just look at the cost of allocating the object, but at the full cost of the lifecycle, from creating the object to reclaiming it when it has become garbage.

Unnecessary consing "exerts pressure" against the garbage collector; it makes garbage collection work more often.

(It's not a Lisp issue. For example, C programs that make lots of calls to `malloc` and `free`, or C++ programs that use `new` and `delete` a lot will also not perform as well as similar programs which are better organized to avoid many of these calls.)

You don't have to be paranoid about avoid consing in Lisp, because that will make programming inconvenient, and some of the tricks for avoiding consing, involving destructive re-use of existing objects, are prone to bugs.

But it can pay to watch out for in consing that happens in inner loops that are executed a large number of times, and in low-level code like utility functions that are intended for wide reuse. For instance suppose that `mapcar` internally built up the result list in reverse, and then put it in the correct order by calling `reverse` instead of `nreverse`. Then, everything that calls `mapcar` would suffer from unnecessary consing.