# Explicitly stack-allocated data

Tags: common-lisp, stack-allocation

I think in most implementations of Common Lisp cons cells are generally/always heap allocated (see [Why is consing in Lisp slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256261/why-is-consing-in-lisp-slow))

Common Lisp does provide a facility for returning multiple values from a function (using `values` when returning and `multiple-value-bind` at the call-site). I'm speculating a bit here, but I think the motivation for this construction is two-fold: 1) make functions like `truncate` easier to use in the typical case where you don't care about the discarded value and 2) make it possible to return multiple values without using a heap-allocated data structure at all and (depending on the implementation (?)) avoiding the heap entirely (and GC overhead later down the road).

Does Common Lisp (or a specific implementation like SBCL maybe) give you the ability to use stack-allocated data (maybe in conjunction with something like weak references) or create composite/large-ish value types (something like structs in C)?

Comment: You can do stack allocation with the `DYNAMIC-EXTENT` declaration. See SBCL manual [6.2 Dynamic-extent allocation](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Dynamic_002dextent-allocation) for example.

Comment: Please see [values function in Common Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22796346/850781).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Common Lisp has a [DYNAMIC-EXTENT](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/d_dynami.htm#dynamic-extent) declaration. Implementations can use this information to stack allocate some data structures - they can also ignore this declaration.

See the respective documentation how some implementations support it:

- [Allegro CL: Stack consing](https://franz.com/support/documentation/10.1/doc/compiling.htm#stack-consing-2)
- [LispWorks: Stack allocation of objects with dynamic extent](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/LW/html/lw-63.htm#pgfId-889717)
- [SBCL: Dynamic-extent allocation](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Dynamic_002dextent-allocation)

Other implementations support it also, but they may lack explicit documentation about it.

The main motivation for explicit support of returning *multiple values* was to get rid of consing / destructuring lists of return values or even putting some results in global variables. Thus one may now be able to return multiple values in registers or via a stack.